# How to configure HSTS headers in traefik

Tags: traefik, hsts

Help needed in configuring traefik using .toml file. The only configuration examples that I was able to find was for cases when used with Docker. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 3):

This section is included in the `Basics` section of Traefik's documentation:

https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/headers/#using-security-headers

You can also see the configuration examples there. They include the settings configuring HSTS headers.

Comment: why this is not a default in traefik?

Answer (score 1):

For people with STS-issues when using Traefik, please take a look at my findings when using STS with self-signed certificates: [How to use STS headers with Traefik when using Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58266122/how-to-use-sts-headers-with-traefik-when-using-docker/58266123#58266123)